# Mongoose - Filter Subdocuments inside multiple documents and get as a plain array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an ecommerce app that has Products with multiple variants. So, variants are stored inside an array in each Product Object.

```
[
    {
      title: "Test"
      description: "test description",
      ....
      ....
      variants: [
        {
           color: "red",
           size: "L"
           ....
           ....
           price: 500
        },
        {
           color: "red",
           size: "M"
           ....
           ....
           price: 500
        },
        {
           color: "red",
           size: "S"
           ....
           ....
           price: 500
        },    
      ]
    }
]
```

Is there a way to filter these products variants by its ID and return as a plain array of variants ignoring they're from different parents but with parent details ?

```
[
        {
           color: "red",
           size: "L"
           ....
           ....
           price: 500,
           parent: {
             title: "Test"
             description: "test description"
           }
        },
        {
           color: "red",
           size: "M"
           ....
           ....
           price: 500,
           parent: {
             title: "Test"
             description: "test description"
           }
        },
        {
           color: "red",
           size: "S"
           ....
           ....
           price: 500,
           parent: {
             title: "Test"
             description: "test description"
           }
        },
        {
           color: "orange",
           size: "S"
           ....
           ....
           price: 500,
           parent: {
             title: "Test 2"
             description: "test description 2"
           }
        },  
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Query1

- add one field named `parent` with the fields that are in the root, except `variants`
- remove those fields, keep the `variants`
- map to add the `parent` field inside the array `variants`
- unwind `variants` and replace the root

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63ef82153601f685eed54a98)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": {"parent": {"title": "$title", "description": "$description"}}},
 {"$unset": ["title", "description"]},
 {"$set": 
   {"variants": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$variants",
        "in": {"$mergeObjects": ["$$this", {"parent": "$parent"}]}}}}},
 {"$unwind": "$variants"},
 {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$variants"}}])
```

Query2

- same as above just with less stages, 1 set to do the 3 first stages

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63ef83583601f685eed54a99)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"title": "$$REMOVE",
    "description": "$$REMOVE",
    "variants": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$variants",
        "in": 
         {"$mergeObjects": 
           ["$$this",
             {"parent": 
               {"title": "$title", "description": "$description"}}]}}}}},
 {"$unwind": "$variants"}, {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$variants"}}])
```